# Custom ontology and RDFs

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs

I created a custom OWL ontology using Protege which is serialized in a tree-based RDF/XML format.

What I want to do is create RDF triples from my predefined classes in custom ontology and store them in RDF file. And query those triples using SPARQL. How can I do this?

=== Update ===

This is what my custom ontology looks like, which has Comment class and 
isAbout object property.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
    <!ENTITY reviews_2 "http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#" >
]>


<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#"
     xml:base="http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:reviews_2="http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl"/>



    <!-- 
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
     -->




    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#isAbout -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&reviews_2;isAbout">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;FunctionalProperty"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Feature"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Review"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- 
    //
    // Data properties
    //
     -->




    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#comment -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&reviews_2;comment">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;FunctionalProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Review"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#rating -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&reviews_2;rating">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;FunctionalProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Review"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;integer"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#type -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&reviews_2;type">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;FunctionalProperty"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Feature"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- 
    //
    // Classes
    //
     -->




    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#Battery -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&reviews_2;Battery">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Feature"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#Body -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&reviews_2;Body">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Feature"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#Camera -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&reviews_2;Camera">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Feature"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#Display -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&reviews_2;Display">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Feature"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#Feature -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&reviews_2;Feature"/>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#Memory -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&reviews_2;Memory">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Feature"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#Platform -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&reviews_2;Platform">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Feature"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#Review -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&reviews_2;Review"/>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#front -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&reviews_2;front">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Camera"/>
    </owl:Class>



    <!-- 
    //
    // Individuals
    //
     -->




    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#Battery -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&reviews_2;Battery">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Battery"/>
        <type rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">battery</type>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#OLED -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&reviews_2;OLED">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Display"/>
        <type rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">OLED</type>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#amoled -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&reviews_2;amoled">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Display"/>
        <type rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">amoled</type>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#fCameraReview -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&reviews_2;fCameraReview">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Review"/>
        <rating rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">3</rating>
        <comment rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">awesome</comment>
        <isAbout rdf:resource="&reviews_2;frontCamera"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#frontCamera -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&reviews_2;frontCamera">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&reviews_2;front"/>
        <type rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">front camera</type>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#review -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&reviews_2;review">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Review"/>
        <rating rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">3</rating>
        <comment rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">great</comment>
        <isAbout rdf:resource="&reviews_2;amoled"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#tt -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&reviews_2;tt">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Review"/>
        <rating rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">3</rating>
        <comment rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">nice one</comment>
        <isAbout rdf:resource="&reviews_2;amoled"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#tt2 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&reviews_2;tt2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Review"/>
        <rating rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">2</rating>
        <comment rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">dfgh</comment>
        <isAbout rdf:resource="&reviews_2;amoled"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#xx -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&reviews_2;xx">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Review"/>
        <rating rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">4</rating>
        <comment rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">great battery</comment>
        <isAbout rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Battery"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#xx2 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&reviews_2;xx2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&reviews_2;Review"/>
        <rating rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">1</rating>
        <comment rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">fghjk</comment>
        <isAbout rdf:resource="&reviews_2;frontCamera"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- 
    //
    // General axioms
    //
     -->

    <rdf:Description>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
        <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="&reviews_2;Battery"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="&reviews_2;Body"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="&reviews_2;Camera"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="&reviews_2;Display"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="&reviews_2;Memory"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="&reviews_2;Platform"/>
        </owl:members>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

And my RDF file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF
      xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
      xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
      xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
      xmlns:cmnt="http://review-analyzer.local/ontologies/reviews_2.owl#"
      xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/">

<cmnt:Comment rdf:ID="me">
    <cmnt:review>Great one!</cmnt:review>
    <cmnt:raitng>5</cmnt:raitng>
    <cmnt:isAbout>
      <cmnt:Display rdf:ID="amoled">
        <cmnt:type>amoled</cmnt:type>
      </cmnt:Display>
    </cmnt:isAbout>
</cmnt:Comment>
</rdf:RDF>
```

So i can't figure it out a way to comment which is created from Comment class.

can't I write something like ?

```
select *
where {
  ?Comment rdf:type ns:Review ;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how"? Just write the RDF file that contains the data. Then load the data into some SPARQL capable tools, e.g. a triple store. Then, execute the SPARQL query.

Comment: @AKSW please see the updated question

Comment: The relationship is `comment -> review`, thus the triple pattern is `?comment cmnt:review ?review .` - please always look at your data in N-Triples (resp. Turtle) format. This is much closer to SPARQL triple patterns

Comment: @AKSW Is there a way that I can use this RDF as a data repository to my ontology? use the data in the RDF file when I query my ontology

Comment: ? load both into the tripe store, then run the query. I still don't get what else you want. Both are RDF files, the ontology is also RDF. You have to load both to the triple store, you can only query what's contained in the triple store. It's just a database for RDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDF/XML is RDF. Any repository or library that accepts SPARQL queries should also accept the file as it is, through whichever loading mechanism the library supports. For example, Jena and ARQ would be able to deal with that as libraries, and Fuseki as a SPARQL endpoint.

Comment: can I use my object property which is defined in my owl ontology to query the RDF, without creating individuals using RDF data ?

Comment: Yes, but if there are no individuals you won't get results.

Comment: that means I have to loop though data and create individuals right

Comment: There is no constraint on how to populate your ontology; if a loop through data is the best way for your application, then it's a perfectly valid approach.

Comment: when I try to get Literal from jena it return's null; when I print nextSolution it'd look like
( ?raitng = "5" ) -> ( ?Comment = <file:///C:/Users/Asus/eclipse-workspace/Review%20Analyzer/rdf/119.rdf#me2> ) ( ?review = "Display is great!" ) -> [Root]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're creating individuals with relative IRIs. Use absolute IRIs, with an explicit namespace.

Comment: please look at this, this is what am i asking  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870530/getliteral-returns-null-when-reading-rdf-file-using-jena